# Which profession can achieve permanent or near-permanent swiftness?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Which skill combos of which professions can reliably achieve an effectively permanent swiftness boon through slot and weapon skills, without chance skills or traits? If there is none, which combos have the highest percentual swiftness duration per cycle?

Comment: Engineer can try to cycle Elixir B and Stimulants from the med kit to get 30 out of 40 seconds under swiftness, assuming perfect execution. Probably far from the most fitting for what you're trying to pull off.

Comment: Guardians and elementalists are most reliable for this

Comment: Guardians are good, but not able to permanent swift

Comment: If you are playing with someone, you can achieve that with two banners from a warrior, as well. With both players spamming [Inspire](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Inspire). Requires you to stop shortly to catch a banner on the ground every 45 seconds, though. Not ideal for fighting, admittedly, but good to run from one place to another.

Comment: @Hackworth complemented the answer adding Guardian and Engineer perspective

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Elementalist

Elementalists have several ways to maintain 100% Swiftness uptime.

One is to put 20 trait points into Air Magic and select the [Quick Glyphs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Quick_Glyphs) and [Inscription](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Inscription_%28trait%29) traits. This will make the Swiftness granted by your [Glyph of Elemental Harmony](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glyph_of_Elemental_Harmony) last as long as the skill's recast time.

Staff Elementalists can combine Glyph of Elemental Harmony, [Windborne Speed](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Windborne_Speed), and [Static Field](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Static_Field_%28staff_skill%29)+[Arcane Wave](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Arcane_Wave) (Lightning/Blast combo). This works regardless of what traits you pick, but you do need to carry Arcane Wave for the blast finisher.

Dagger/Dagger Elementalists can combine Glyph of Elemental Harmony with the [Zephyr's Boon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Zephyr%27s_Boon) trait in Air Magic and their [Frost Aura](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Frost_Aura) and [Shocking Aura](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shocking_Aura) skills, as well as [Ride the Lightning](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ride_the_Lightning) and [Updraft](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Updraft). As an added bonus, 5 points in Air Magic lets you move 10% faster when attuned to Air.

### Engineer

The [Speedy Kits](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Speedy_Kits) trait grants Swiftness when changing kits.

All you have to do, besides having the trait, is keep on changing kits in order to keep your Swiftness up. You will need at least 1 kit skill in a utility slot in order to actually equip it. You can equip/unequip/equip the same kit to keep the swiftness flowing.

### Guardian

Staff Guardians can use [Symbol of Swiftness](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Symbol_of_Swiftness), which grants 8 seconds of Swiftness with a 15 second cooldown. For utilities, you can use [Retreat](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/%22Retreat!%22) (20 seconds swiftness) and [Save Yourselves](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Save_Yourselves) (10 seconds swiftness). Using a single cycle of those skills together will provide a total of 38 seconds of Swiftness.

Comment: I run perma-swiftness on my ranger using Warhorn and http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Superior_Rune_of_the_Centaur then I can cycle horn and heal to keep swiftness going.

Answer (score 2):

I believe warriors can achieve permanent swiftness with the warhorn skill [charge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Charge_%28warrior_skill%29) (10 s, 20 cooldown) and the elite [Signet of Rage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Signet_of_Rage) (30 s, 60 s cooldown).

Comment: That can only give you 50 seconds of swiftness per minute without additional buffs.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Engineers (PvP specifically), I've been running a PvP build that focuses on maintaining swiftness and have enjoyed it:

http://gw2skills.net/editor/?fcAQJAqalspaen1y3F1LJxoCcG0j8WfAISR+x8nCsF;T8AAzyqEUJpSVliKqkMJJSymkLJZSjROjMHB

Key points:

- Infused Precision grants you swiftness after roughly every other critical hit.
- Sigils for chance on critical quickness.
- Runes for increased swiftness duration.
- Invigorating Speed grants you 5 seconds of vigor whenever you gain swiftness.
- The Slick Shoes secondary "F" skill gives you 5 seconds of ad-hoc swiftness to help fill the gaps.
- Secondary build focus: applying the burning condition.

In a PvP setting, I prefer to not be caught off guard while switching kits, but for perma swiftness agnostic of combat effectiveness it is a viable option.